# A better online editor for GitHub.com and GitHub Pages?

Tags: github

After not being able to set the default wrap setting on GitHub.com and finding no answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45401048/setting-githubs-soft-wrap-option-to-be-on-by-default) SO question, and seeing problems with a workaround solution for tab indent size [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894791/change-github-online-editor-tab-indent-size), I'm wondering if there is a better editor for GitHub when online using 'Edit file'?

I know most dedicated devs use GH as a repo and for versioning, but a lot of users start small projects with it and it would be nice to have common code editing features built into the online editor. Even better would be a quick preview for changes to the GitHub Pages static sites, similar to StackOverflow's text preview.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I've found [prose.io](https://prose.io) and [Real Time HTML Editor](https://htmledit.squarefree.com/) in combination to make some quick edits to my GH page. I'm just trying to reformat a GSheet iframe to fit on the page, through trying different url prameters. The url is very long and needs to be wrapped. And the test cycle needs to be short as possible for these small changes.

---

Ive also opened a GitHub feedback post here. Please upvote it: https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/13206

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are looking for a code editor or a page editor. If latter, I'd recommend checking out JekyllPad [github pages editor](https://www.JekyllPad.com).

Disclaimer: I am the developer of it.

Comment: Its not really an answer if you are asking a question. You can improve your answer by listing a few features of your editor